# Acumatica - Grid in PXTabItem on PXSmartPanel Not Appearing on Screen

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have a `PXSmartPanel` on the Sales Orders form (SO301000) in Acumatica ERP (v21.109.0018). In the `PXSmartPanel` I have a `PXTab` with two `PXTabItem`'s. Each tab item has a `PXGrid` in it.

Whenever the smart panel opens, the grid in the first tab item shows with the correct data. But when I select the other tab item, the grid doesn't show at all (no data, no column names, no toolbar actions). I'm not sure if there's an attribute that I'm missing, but any help would be appreciated.

Here is my ASPX code for the `PXSmartPanel`. The grid with the ID "GridKitNonStkComponents" is the one that isn't showing:

```
<px:PXSmartPanel runat="server" ID="KitComponentsPanel" DesignView="Content" AllowResize="true" 
    AcceptButtonID="KitComponentSaveButton" CancelButtonID="KitComponentCancelButton" LoadOnDemand="true"
    CaptionVisible="true" Caption="Kit Component Items" Key="KitComponentsPanel"
    AutoRepaint="true" style="position:static;" Height="400px" Width="560px">
    <px:PXTab ID="kitCompTab" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="85%">
        <Items>
            <px:PXTabItem Text="Stock Components">
                <Template>
                    <px:PXGrid runat="server" ID="GridKitStkComponents" Height="100%" Width="100%" SyncPosition="true">
                        <Levels>
                            <px:PXGridLevel DataMember="KitStkComponents">
                                <Columns>
                                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="CompInventoryID" Width="70" CommitChanges="True" />
                                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="CompDescription" Width="280" />
                                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="ComponentQty" />
                                </Columns>
                            </px:PXGridLevel>
                        </Levels>
                        <ActionBar Position="Top">
                            <Actions>
                                <AddNew MenuVisible="True" />
                                <Save MenuVisible="False" Enabled="False" />
                                <Search MenuVisible="False" Enabled="False" />
                                <NoteShow Enabled="False" MenuVisible="False" />
                                <Refresh MenuVisible="True" />
                                <Delete MenuVisible="True" />
                                <AdjustColumns MenuVisible="True" />
                                <ExportExcel MenuVisible="True" />
                            </Actions>
                            <CustomItems>
                                <px:PXToolBarButton>
                                    <AutoCallBack Command="ResetStkCompsToDefault" Target="ds">
                                        <Behavior CommitChanges="true" />
                                    </AutoCallBack>
                                </px:PXToolBarButton>
                            </CustomItems>
                        </ActionBar>
                        <AutoSize Enabled="true" />
                    </px:PXGrid>
                </Template>
            </px:PXTabItem>
            <px:PXTabItem Text="Non-Stock Components" LoadOnDemand="true">
                <Template>
                    <px:PXGrid runat="server" ID="GridKitNonStkComponents" Height="100%" Width="100%" SyncPosition="true">
                        <Levels>
                            <px:PXGridLevel DataMember="KitNonStkComponents">
                                <Columns>
                                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="CompInventoryID" Width="70" CommitChanges="True" />
                                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="CompDescription" Width="280" />
                                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="ComponentQty" />
                                </Columns>
                            </px:PXGridLevel>
                        </Levels>
                        <ActionBar Position="Top">
                            <Actions>
                                <AddNew MenuVisible="True" />
                                <Save MenuVisible="False" Enabled="False" />
                                <Search MenuVisible="False" Enabled="False" />
                                <NoteShow Enabled="False" MenuVisible="False" />
                                <Refresh MenuVisible="True" />
                                <Delete MenuVisible="True" />
                                <AdjustColumns MenuVisible="True" />
                                <ExportExcel MenuVisible="True" />
                            </Actions>
                            <CustomItems>
                                <px:PXToolBarButton>
                                    <AutoCallBack Command="ResetNonStkCompsToDefault" Target="ds">
                                        <Behavior CommitChanges="true" />
                                    </AutoCallBack>
                                </px:PXToolBarButton>
                            </CustomItems>
                        </ActionBar>
                        <AutoSize Enabled="true" />
                    </px:PXGrid>
                </Template>
            </px:PXTabItem>
        </Items>
    </px:PXTab>
    
    <px:PXPanel ID="KitComponentButtonPanel" runat="server" SkinID="Buttons">
        <px:PXButton ID="KitComponentSaveButton" runat="server" DialogResult="OK" Text="Save" />
        <px:PXButton ID="KitComponentCancelButton" runat="server" DialogResult="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
    </px:PXPanel>
</px:PXSmartPanel>
```

Here is the code for my graph extension (at the moment, the EditKitComponents action just opens the smart panel):

```
    public class SOOrderEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
    {
        public static bool IsActive() => true;

        #region Selects / Views

        public SelectFrom<SOLineKitComponent>.
                Where<SOLineKitComponent.soOrderType.IsEqual<SOLine.orderType.FromCurrent>.
                    And<SOLineKitComponent.soOrderNbr.IsEqual<SOLine.orderNbr.FromCurrent>>.
                    And<SOLineKitComponent.soLineNbr.IsEqual<SOLine.lineNbr.FromCurrent>>.
                    And<SOLineKitComponent.kitInventoryID.IsEqual<SOLine.inventoryID.FromCurrent>>.
                    And<SOLineKitComponent.stkItem.IsEqual<True>>>.View KitStkComponents;

        public SelectFrom<SOLineKitComponent>.
                Where<SOLineKitComponent.soOrderType.IsEqual<SOLine.orderType.FromCurrent>.
                    And<SOLineKitComponent.soOrderNbr.IsEqual<SOLine.orderNbr.FromCurrent>>.
                    And<SOLineKitComponent.soLineNbr.IsEqual<SOLine.lineNbr.FromCurrent>>.
                    And<SOLineKitComponent.kitInventoryID.IsEqual<SOLine.inventoryID.FromCurrent>>.
                    And<SOLineKitComponent.stkItem.IsEqual<False>>>.View KitNonStkComponents;

        public SelectFrom<SOOrder>.View KitComponentsPanel;

        #endregion

        #region Actions

        public PXAction<SOOrder> EditKitComponents;
        [PXButton]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Edit Kit Components")]
        public virtual void editKitComponents()
        {
            if(KitComponentsPanel.AskExt() == WebDialogResult.OK)
            {

            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Here is what the smart panel looks like when the different tab items are selected:

[Tab Item with Grid Showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRBHO.png)

[Tab Item with Grid Not Showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksCBt.png)

Comment: Could you please add your PXGraphExtension code to the question?

Comment: Yes, @SamvelPetrosov. I've added the PXGraphExtension.

Comment: Try switching the tab content, is it always content of second tab that is empty?

Comment: Also try with property LoadOnDemand="false" on second tab

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the **"LoadOnDemand"** to false for the whole **PXSmartPanel** to have the second tab working.

```
<px:PXSmartPanel runat="server" ID="KitComponentsPanel"
...
LoadOnDemand="False"
...
>
```

I would also consider setting LoadOnDemand to false for the second tab.

```
<px:PXTabItem Text="Non-Stock Components" LoadOnDemand="false">
```